# How to change default upload sizing of Magento (1.9) product images

Tags: image, magento

I'm trying to change the default upload resizing for the Small Image that is used for the catalog images.

Magento docs say to go to Config > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image

There, you can set the sizing for each type of image - Thumb, Small, Base.

I changed the Small Image size to 1000px (before it was 210px), but it is still uploading/resizing pictures to 210px. I have tried refreshing all Caches and Re-indexed, logged out and logged back in (just to cover all my bases). Each time I did these things, I re-uploaded images. I even tried uploading images with different names, just in case the image with that name was cached in my browser already.

I'm probably just doing this entirely wrong. How do I get these parameters set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out!

Had to make an edit in the list.phtml file for my design theme:

```
<?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
```

to

```
<?php $_imgSize = 1000; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open media.phtml file using a text editor of your theme and change the size of image like bolow:

```
$_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(300).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
```